# Errors prior to write-output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, output

I'm writing a function to collect WMI information from various computers. the first thing I do is check to see if I can access the current computer and if not I write-error and Continue. My question is, how can I have the errors written to the screen *then* the results of the successful calls?
(abridged code:)

```
Function Get-Info
{
    Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string[]] $computerName = "." )
    Process
    {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
        {
            if (-Not $(test-connection $computer -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) )
            {
                Write-Error "Unable to access $computer"
                continue
            }
            $Info = get-WMIObject -Class <someClass> -ComputerName $Computer
            $result = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                 Prop1 = $Info.Property
                 <# ... #> }
            Write-Output $Result
       }
   }
}
```

When I query a collection of systems, I get `info, <error>, info, <error>` and not `<error>,<error>,info...` which is what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: You want all errors to print before all successful results?

Comment: Could you not capture the results in an array `$results += $result` the outside of the foreach loop `Write-Output $Results` ?

Comment: Note that `Write-Error` and `Write-Output` write to different streams. Messages are printed sequentially for any single stream, but there is no guaranteed order across different streams.

Comment: Yes arco444 - errors before output.

Comment: Trying to avoid collecting output. Looking at some of the "Best Practice" in books in articles I've seen to use Write-Output (or leave the output as the last entry to go to the pipe) and I'm trying to make the best function for reusability.

Comment: You must collect one stream, otherwise you can't defer output of that stream until output of the other stream is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Just accumulate your results in a variable, then output that after it's finished and all the errors are written:

```
$Result = $computers | Get-Info
$Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I just collected all of the errors into $errorComputers, and all of the successful Computers into $validComputers, then display them at the end of the code.  Note that is approach does not make good use of the PowerShell pipeline (At all!) but it achieves the goal you're looking for, listing errors before valid entries.

```
Function Get-Info
{
Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
[string[]] $computerName = "." )
Process
{
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
    {
        if (-Not $(test-connection $computer -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) )
        {
            $errorcomputers += $computer
            continue
        }
        $Info = get-WMIObject -Class <someClass> -ComputerName $Computer
        $result = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
             Prop1 = $Info.Property
             <# ... #> }
        $validComputers += $Result
   }
}
$errorcomputers | ForEach-Object {
   Write-Warning "Unable to contact $PSitem"
   }
$validComputers
}
```

Now, in this second example, I've used Try/Catch instead of your previous logic.  This should ensure that your errors are displayed first, and maintains function of the process block for speed.

```
Function Get-Info
{
Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
[string[]] $computerName = "." )
Process
{
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
    {

    try {test-connection $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop}
   catch{Write-Error "Unable to access $computer"
                Continue}
        $Info = get-WMIObject -Class <someClass> -ComputerName $Computer
        $result = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
             Prop1 = $Info.Property
             <# ... #> }
        Write-Output $Result
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the input. I guess there isn't a great way to do what I want to do. As 1RedOne pointed out, I want to use good practice for the pipeline and I'd rather not collect objects and instead use write-output on each individual object (good use of the pipeline).